# html5 video is not playing on android phone

Tags: android, html5-video

i'm using html5 video player from http://www.videojs.com/ to play videos. the video works on normal pc but on android it doesn't play here's the link http://www.mawk3y.net/video/ and here's the head code

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video.js"></script>
```

body code

```
<video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="uploads/example.jpg"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="uploads/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 <source src="uploads/video.webm" type='video/webm'>
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plays ok for me on android 4.4.2, what version of android are you testing on. Older versions of Android have shaky support for the video element, particularly 2.2 or below